# UIWebView doesn't rotate with multiple tabs application

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

I am using UIWebView to display the PDF and Word documents on iPhone. I want them to auto rotate when device orientation changes. For that I have added following delegate method. Something weird is happening though. It works fine when I have I have only one tab which has UIWebView. It loads document fine and also rotate perfectly but when I add another tab, it doesn't rotate..! While debugging I could see that when I have two table, it receives the rotation event only for UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight and UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft. Could any one please help me to get rid of this.

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
     return YES;

}

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using a tab bar controller for the tabs, you need to make sure that the views on all tabs support the different device orientations. Try implementing the methods in the tab bar controller class.

Comment: You are right. From http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1688/_index.html, following fourth point is related to my problem:
 
All child view controllers in your UITabBarController or UINavigationController do not agree on a common orientation set.... That is, they all should return YES for the same orientation positions.
 
Could you tell me how to get rid/workaround to this? Basically I don't want all view controllers inside UITabBarController to rotate. I just want some of them to rotate.
 
Thanks.

Comment: I don't think that is achievable, unfortunately. Only having some views rotating in a tab bar application strides against Apple's guidelines.

Comment: Okay. Then if we don't rotate the view, is there anyway to reset the webview content in landscape or portrait mode? We can detect the orientation changes by adding Notifier and also identify the current orientation and based on that set the webview content.

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe rotating the webview with [webView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( floatValue )]; would work?